# How to replicate and remove a form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Currently i have to make a form that can add fields and remove them if you dont want them. For example the code below now displays 3 fields to fill in, as you can see the first field does not have a remove button however the other 2 does. there is also an add button which duplicates a field. Currently the duplicate, is duplicating id="2" which kind of works but once i remove id="2" i cant duplicate it. So my question is that, is it possible to duplicate id="1" at the same time have a button appear beside the duplicated field that removes it. I am restricted to only HTML, Css, and Javascript. Thx.

```js
function removesomething(){
 document.getElementById("1").remove();
}
function removesomething2(){
 document.getElementById("2").remove();
}
function removesomething3(){
 document.getElementById("3").remove();
}
var i = 0;
 function duplicate() {
 var parent = document.getElementById("2");

    var clone = parent.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "2" + ++i; 
    parent.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```css
.locationsector legend{
  font-size:2em;
 }

 .locationsector{
  border-radius:5px;
  border:5px solid black;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:0.7%;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
 }
 label{
  padding:2%;
 }

 img{
  text-align:center;
  margin:2%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:10px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  width:150px;
  height:112px;
 }
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset class="locationsector">
 <legend>Field 1</legend>
  <label for="north1" id="1">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file"  required="required"  />
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
  </label>
      
  <br>
        
  <label for="north2" id="2">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file" id="2" required="required"/>
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
   <button onclick="removesomething2()">Remove</button>
  </label>
       
  <br>
       
  <label for="north3" id="3">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file"  required="required"/>
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
   <button onclick="removesomething3()">Remove</button>
  </label> 
       
  <br>
  <button onclick="duplicate();">Add</button>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Try this demo: http://www.quackfuzed.com/demos/jQuery/dynamicField/multipleFields.cfm

Answer (score 0):

Try this [demo](http://www.mustbebuilt.co.uk/2012/07/27/adding-form-fields-dynamically-with-jquery/). Works like a charm:) And now you can either save created input fields in an aray, or search qith jQuery all inputs inside of your form that name starts with `var`

Answer (score 0):

See below. Instead of removing elements by id you can remove them by reference. When you click on add you can clone the first element and append the button to it.

Remove clicked button's parent:

```
function removesomething(e){
    e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}
```

Clone the first element and add the remove button to the clone:

```
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "removesomething(this)");
button.innerHTML = "Remove";
clone.appendChild(button);
```

```js
function removesomething(e){
    e.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(e.parentNode);
}

var i = 0;
 function duplicate() {
var parent = document.getElementById("1");

    var clone = parent.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "2" + ++i; 

var button = document.createElement('button');
button.type = 'button';
button.setAttribute("onclick", "removesomething(this)");
button.innerHTML = "Remove";


    clone.appendChild(button);
    parent.appendChild(clone);

}
```

```css
.locationsector legend{
  font-size:2em;
 }

 .locationsector{
  border-radius:5px;
  border:5px solid black;
  width:30%;
  margin-left:0.7%;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
 }
 label{
  padding:2%;
 }

 img{
  text-align:center;
  margin:2%;
  display:inline-block;
  border:10px solid black;
  padding:5px;
  width:150px;
  height:112px;
 }
```

```html
<form>
<fieldset class="locationsector">
 <legend>Field 1</legend>
  <label for="north1" id="1">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file"  required="required"  />
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
  </label>
      
  <br>
        
  <label for="north2" id="2">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file" id="2" required="required"/>
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
   <button id="2" onclick="removesomething(this)">Remove</button>
  </label>
       
  <br>
       
  <label for="north3" id="3">Choose a Picture 
   <input type="file"  required="required"/>
   <img class="target" src="#" alt="Choose and Upload" />
   <button id="3" onclick="removesomething(this)">Remove</button>
  </label> 
       
  <br>
  <button onclick="duplicate();">Add</button>
</fieldset>
<button onclick="check()">Submit</button>
</form>
```